# Reuse colour in 2 different lines matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib is it possible to use the same colour for 2 lines on the same graph? If yes, can you give an example in python.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is :

```
import matplolib.pyplot as plt

X = [0,1,2,3]
Y = [1,1,2,3]
Z = [2,3,5,7]

plt.plot(X,Y,color='b')
plt.plot(X,Z,color='b')

plt.show()
```

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

Comment: The oroblem I had was due to some other coding I'd written.